# is there any way to pass a parameter to $.change() method ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've written a function which gets called when input textbox text changes -

On HTML -

```
<input id="unique" type="text" data-ng-change="KeywordChange(filterKey)" ng-model="$parent.filterKey">
```

in Controller

```
$scope.KeywordChange = function (filterKey) {
    //some logic goes here
}
```

Keyword change function works well when input text box text changes. but I want this function NOT to be called when I change value of input text box like this

```
 $('#unique').val('');
 $('#unique').change();
```

and I've to change textbox value programatically - so is there any option to know keywordChange function is being called by actual text change in textBox or called by programatic call to `$('#unique').change();`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n0kfdbh3/ check this fiddle this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value of the textbox (that is bound to some data) programmatically in AngularJs, then all you need to do is update the corresponding Model.

Using jQuery to update the UI is most definitely not recommended.

You'd need to just update the property "filterKey" in JavaScript from within your AngularJs code.

Comment: Yes, certainly that's the reason we use AngularJs but in my case somehow - I need to use jQuery to update the textbox value.

Comment: Where are you trying to update it from? Is it from within the same controller? or somewhere else? if you are updating the value of the textbox from outside the controller, then you're not using AngularJs properly. The controller would be responsible for the UI updates via the model binding. If you are after updating the Ui from outside the controller, then you need to either re-factor your code or resort to controller communication using $broadcast or $emit.

Comment: I think you are right - I need to restructure my code and limit it to controller when it comes to updating UI. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) since all you care about are physical key strokes?